# convert text to html by php

Tags: php, html, email

I created a form in html and use php to send email

```
<form action="xxxxxx" method="post">
  <textarea rows="15" cols="80" name="texttosend" >
    Here is the list
    1) xxxx
    2) yyyy
    3) zzzz
  </textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="do"    value="admin" />
  <input type="hidden" name="page"  value="mytext" />
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="sendmail" value="Send" />
</form>
```

In php, I capture the content of the textarea and send it as html by setting the header of the email as

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
```

However, the email sent out lose all the format (I mean seems all the line return are gone and all line are shown in one line. So I try to wrap the content of textarea within <p> </p> but it doesn't work again. What's the right way to send html message in the way as it type in the textarea?

Comment: there is no HTML in your message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `htmentites()`

```
echo htmentites($_POST['texttosend']);
```

Comment: Oh, it reminds me one thing. I confuse the <p> tag with the <pre>. What I was to do is to wrap $_POST['texttosend']) with <pre> but I make it to <p>. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make your header

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
```

as there is no HTML in your message